# how to filter duplicate values in xml tags

Tags: xml

I need to check an XML file on duplicate values in a tag.
Below is an example of a small part of the file.
The value of tag 'csvpartname' must be checked on duplicates because it may only can be used once. 
I've no idea how to do this, so any help is very welcome!

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE NmLoader SYSTEM "standardX24.dtd">
<NmLoader>

<csvPart handler="wt.part.LoadPart.createPart" >
    <csvuser></csvuser>
    <csvpartName>Configured Fan</csvpartName>
    <csvpartNumber>0000023860</csvpartNumber>
    <csvtype>separable</csvtype>
    <csvgenericType>standard</csvgenericType>
    <csvcollapsible></csvcollapsible>
    <csvlogicbasePath></csvlogicbasePath>
</csvPart>

<csvPart handler="wt.part.LoadPart.createPart" >
    <csvuser></csvuser>
    <csvpartName>Configured Fan</csvpartName>
    <csvpartNumber>0000023861</csvpartNumber>
    <csvtype>separable</csvtype>
    <csvgenericType>standard</csvgenericType>
    <csvcollapsible></csvcollapsible>
    <csvlogicbasePath></csvlogicbasePath>
</csvPart>

</NmLoader>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks to see if the csvpartName appears more than once in the XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

<xsl:key name="k" match="csvPart" use="csvpartName" />

<xsl:template match='/'>
  <html>
  <body>
<xsl:apply-templates select='//csvpartName'/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='*'>

<xsl:if test='count(key("k", .)) &gt; 1'>
<p>
<xsl:value-of select='.'/> is used 
<xsl:value-of select='count(key("k", .))'/> times
</p>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: uhhh, how do I run this code and associate it with the xml file I want to check?

Comment: The simplest way is to save the above text (as CheckPartName.xsl for example) in the same folder as your .xml file and change the first line in your xml file to read <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CheckPartName.xsl"?>  you will then be able to open the .xml file in any modern browser.

Comment: hello FonnParr, since your perfect solution on my problem, i would like to ask you if you could take a look at my second question... Maybe you can help me with that problem to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651583/how-to-filter-duplicate-combination-of-xml-tags